# list_display age is no way to be calculated

Tags: django, django-models

can someone please help me with this error in django?

**ERROR MESSAGE:**
<class 'members.admin.MemberAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[4]' refers to 'age', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'MemberAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'members.Member'.

Here are the codes of models.py and admin.py

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date


class Member(models.Model):
  firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  joined_date = models.DateField(null=True)
  dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  get_age= models.IntegerField(null=True)
 
  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}"

class Meta:
    ordering = ('lastname')

@property
def get_age(self):
  if(self.dob != None):
    get_age = date.today().year - self.dob.year / 365.25
    return get_age
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Member

# Register your models here.

@admin.register(Member)
class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'joined_date', 'dob' 'get_age')
  
admin.site.register(Member, MemberAdmin)
```

I already tried finding solutions from different sites but until now I can't find the correct solution for my problem. Hoping someone will help. I am expecting to add a computed age field in models in django.

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Edit the question and add all code, output, and error messages as plain text.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Please provide code instead of images of the code. Include the code between triple Backticks (`) and type the name of the programming language after that. For example, type triple backticks (and the e.g python), then at the next line paste the code, then triple backticks at the next line after the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property should be part of the model, so:

```
from datetime import date


class Member(models.Model):
    # …
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    # …

    DisplayFields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'joining_date', 'dob', 'age']

    @property
    def age(self):
        nw = date.today()
        dob = self.dob
        if dob:
            return (
                dob.year - nw.year - ((nw.month, nw.day) < (dob.month, dob.day))
            )
```

You can also add a description to the field and make it orderable with:

```
from datetime import date

from django.contrib import admin


class Member(models.Model):
    # …
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    # …

    DisplayFields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'joining_date', 'dob', 'age']

    @property
    @admin.display(ordering='-dob', description='age in years')
    def age(self):
        nw = date.today()
        dob = self.dob
        if dob:
            return (
                dob.year - nw.year - ((nw.month, nw.day) < (dob.month, dob.day))
            )
```

---

> **Note**: A property normally has *no* `get_…` prefix: If you call this as `x.get_age` it suggests a method, not a property, you therefore probably should rewrite `get_age` to `age`.

Comment: The formula for the age is correct and I followed your note regarding the age and changed it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I checked your code. The error says that index 4 of the list_display is wrong. The 4th index of the list_display is `get_age` which there is no way to be calculated. You dont have a field with this name, and also don't have a method in your admin class. I suggest you delete this item from the list or define a method in the admin class.
BTW please always provide code instead of image and also I suggest to include the list_display in the admin instead of importing it from the model class.

Comment: I edited my post and followed your instructions, it solved my problem but, there is still no computed get_age field in models in django admin interface.

Comment: @CristyFernandez You have to add the property to the model. Also you can define a method with that name. The `get_age` should be defined as a method.

Comment: Thank you for the help sir, I followed your instructions and it help me solved my problem.